# how to close an application in android

Tags: android

Is there any proper way as suggested by google or android official documentation to close an application in android with out using any task killer tools ....

I ask this question as a android use not as developer.....

Comment: Ask the question at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you should not do it. System will close the application as it will go low on memory.

Comment: moved to http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should be on http://android.stackexchange.com because, you already said it, you are asking as a user and not as a developer.